# Read registry data value from a REG_SZ type that contains a space

Tags: vb.net, registry

I've been banging my head on the wall on this, I happened to fetch this code from another solution

So basically I need to read the registry, check if the value in it matches a pre-set value on the application and report yes or no.

It is not an integer, it's a string of letters and numbers, but the name of the key has a space and it throws an exception.

```
Using sk As RegistryKey = rkLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\X\41821-SAP-GUIPL8HF1-7700.1.8.1162-EN-GBL-R3", False)
Dim nValue As String = sk.GetValue("Application Name")
If nValue = "GUIPL8HF1" Then
Timer2.Stop()
End If
End Using
```

I get the exception thrown at `Dim nValue As String = sk.GetValue("Application Name")`

the original code works well for when the values are numbers and no spaces on the keys, for example;

```
Using sk As RegistryKey = rkLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services", False)
Dim nValue As Integer = CType(sk.GetValue("fDenyTSConnections"), Integer)
If nValue = "1" Then
RDPstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
RDPstatus.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
End If
End Using
```

basically, I need the above code to work for the first example where the value data is not a number and the value name has a space on it.

On a sidenote, another solution attempted was the following code:

```
Dim rk1 As RegistryKey
Dim rk2 As RegistryKey
rk1 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
rk2 = rk1.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\X\41821-SAP-GUIPL8HF1-7700.1.8.1162-EN-GBL-R3")
Dim ST As String = rk2.GetValue("Application Name")
If ST = "GUIPL8HF1" Then
TIMER2.Stop()
End If
```

it throws the same exception at `Dim ST As String = rk2.GetValue("Application Name")`

---

I'm compiling at 64b, the project has x64 as processor selected.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot showing this value in regedit?

Comment: What exception are you getting? You haven't even said. II just tried equivalent code and it worked perfectly well. I added a new value under HKLM\Software and accepted the default name ("New Value #1"). I then used your code with the subkey and value names changed and it worked without issue. The only other change was declaring `ST` as type `Object`, which is required when you do the right thing and turn `Option Strict On`.

Comment: `GetValue` returns an `Object` reference, because it can return different types of objects. Your original code converts that to an `Integer` using `CType`. You should be doing something similar for a `String`, e.g. `Dim st = CStr(rk2.GetValue("Application Name"))`. I have no idea whether this will solve your problem because, without the error message, we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: JM thanks for your reply!, my bad, the error is "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: OMG i just realized something, this is because that key does not exist yet, now it makes sense, ive been running in circles until I attempted your suggestions

Comment: ok now i just need to get a presence checker, if key does not exist do this, kind of thing

Comment: You can call `GetValueNames` to see whether a particular value exists, or you can provide a default value when calling `GetValue` and that will be returned if no such value exists.

Comment: If you really do mean that the key doesn't exist, rather than the value doesn't exist, then there is also `GetSubKeyNames`.

Comment: Ok although your suggestions didn't solved my issue initially, your hints made me realize somethings and succeed with this, I ended up adding a 'isnothing' check on SK and that was the hit to discard the exception, like if key exist do this else other.

Comment: The code I ended up using is:
'
Using sk As RegistryKey = rkLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\X\41821-SAP-GUIPL8HF1-7700.1.8.1162-EN-GBL-R3", False)
If sk IsNot Nothing Then
Dim nValue As String = sk.GetValue("Application Name")
If nValue = "GUIPL8HF1" Then
sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
sapinstall.Enabled = False
Else
sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
sapinstall.Enabled = True
End If
Else
sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
sapinstall.Enabled = True
End If
End Using
End Using'

 Thank you for your great assistance >.<!!

Comment: Don't provide your solution in comments. Post an answer and accept it. That's if you're able to. I'm not 100% sure that a brand new user can do so but, generally speaking, that's how this site works. If an issue is resolved, the question should have an answer. If one is not provided by someone else, the person asking the question should provide one.  The idea is that it will help others in the future with similar problems, not just the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I ended up using to avoid the object reference error trigger is:

```
Using sk As RegistryKey = rkLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\X\41821-SAP-GUIPL8HF1-7700.1.8.1162-EN-GBL-R3", False)
    If sk IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim nValue As String = sk.GetValue("Application Name") 
        If nValue = "GUIPL8HF1" 
        Then
            sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
            sapinstall.Enabled = False 
        Else
            sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
            sapinstall.Enabled = True
        End If 
    Else 
        sappatchstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
        sapinstall.Enabled = True 
    End If 
End Using
```

End Using

Thank you very much for your hints and support @jmcilhinney